# problem of useState hook while doing it with context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i'm trying to register user on some website and save its data in local storage on every page i need to use context for that, so when i tried to do this without context it all worked and i was saving data in local storage but now i  do it with context and it broke and in console.log when i type something in input it shows undefined and useState doesn't work and add items to the object
below code is  app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Question from "./Question";
import Form from "./Form";
import Language from "./Language";
import Photo from "./Photo";
import Fin from "./Fin";
import CustomizedSteppers from "./Step";
import { createContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";
export const StepperContext = createContext({ step: 0, setStep: () => {} });
export const PagesContext = createContext({ info: {}, setInfo: () => {} });

function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const val = useMemo(() => ({ info, setInfo }), [info]);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ step, setStep }), [step]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StepperContext.Provider value={val}>
        <StepperContext.Provider value={value}>
          <CustomizedSteppers>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" index element={<Form />} />
                <Route path="Question" index element={<Question />} />
                <Route path="Language" index element={<Language />} />
                <Route path="Photo" index element={<Photo />} />
                <Route path="Finish" index element={<Fin />} />
              </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </CustomizedSteppers>
        </StepperContext.Provider>
      </StepperContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the form :

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { useState, useContext, createContext,useEffect} from "react";
import MaterialUIPickers from "./Datepicker";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import CustomizedSteppers from "./Step";
import { PagesContext, StepperContext } from "./App";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Form() {
  const { step, setStep } = useContext(StepperContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { info, setInfo } = useContext(PagesContext); 
  console.log(info)
  console.log(step)

  useEffect(() => {
  console.log(info)
  
   
  }, [info])
  

  const next = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("info", JSON.stringify(info));
    setStep(1);
    navigate("Question");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <CustomizedSteppers /> */}
      <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
          "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
      />
      <div className="input">
        <TextField
          color="secondary"
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="First name"
          variant="outlined"
          value={info ? info.firstName : ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(info.firstName)
            setInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, firstName: e.target.value }));
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          color="secondary"
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="Last name"
          variant="outlined"
          value={info ? info.lastName : ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, lastName: e.target.value }));
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="outlined-number"
          type="number"
          color="secondary"
          placeholder="Phone number"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          value={info ? info.phoneNumber : ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, phoneNumber: e.target.value }));
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="City"
          color="secondary"
          variant="outlined"
          type="text"
          value={info ? info.city : ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, city: e.target.value }));
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="Email"
          color="secondary"
          variant="outlined"
          type="email"
          value={info ? info.email : ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, email: e.target.value }));
          }}
        />
        <MaterialUIPickers></MaterialUIPickers>
      </div>
      <Button
        onClick={next}
        style={{ width: "700px" }}
        color="secondary"
        variant="contained"
      >
        Next
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: `i need to use context for that`   Why?

Comment: because i have 4 pages and on every page i need to use setInfo and add other information to that main user object

Comment: So why does a `useContext` help you with that.?   Also why do you have `<StepperContext.Provider>` twice with different values, the first one here is going to be totally ignored.

Comment: Have you tried using context without `useMemo`?

Comment: useContext is helping with it because i share the state with it doesnt it ?

Comment: no i havent tried it without useMemo

Comment: Your first `<StepperContext.Provider..` I assume you meant to do `<PagesContext.Provider value={val}>`